# tengo problemas con carga de imágenes en Iphone

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, imagen

Estoy construyendo una pagina que lleva alguna imagenes y tengo el siguiente problema. En todas las plataformas las imágenes se cargan correctamente, salvo en Iphone y no probé en Ipad, en realidad probé solo en el Iphone de un amigo. No dispongo de otros dispositivos y yo uso android, el tema es que en el Iphone solo me carga las .png, las .jpg no las carga y solo pone lo que dice el ALT. He probado cargarlas por html y por css y pasa lo mismo. Dejo un ejemplo del código utilizado a ver si tengo algun error o alguien puede ayudarme ya que no encontre info al respecto para darme cuenta. Muchas Gracias, y disculpen mi ignorancia!!
este codigo lo uso con el logo de Whatsapp para envío de msjs.

`<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=00.000.000"><img style="float: left;" src="/images/logowapp.jpg" alt="wapp"></a>00.0000.000`

Comment: El código que muestras es valido y no hay ningún impedimento en safari para cargar imágenes, salvo que estés usando algo preprocesador en las imágenes y tengas habilitado el formato *webp*  este no tiene soporte en versiones de safari inferiores a la 14

Comment: Arturo gracias por tu ayuda. Como di muchas vueltas al asunto y no encontre solucion pase las imagenes a formato .png y ahora las muestra bien. No se cual puede ser el problema con las .jpg, aunque entiendo que en .png es un formato de carga mas lenta en el caso de esta web no se nota mucho la diferencia.